# Meteor.js affecting only newly inserted child template

Tags: javascript, meteor

These are templates:

```
<template name="postsList">
  {{#each posts}}
    {{>postItem}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="postItem">
  <div class="more-less">
    <div class="more-block">
      <p>{{{text}}}</p>             
    </div>
    <p class="continued">…</p>
    <a href="#" class="show-more">[ + ]</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

When **posts** is updated with new post, **postItem** is inserted to **postsLists**. How can I apply this only for new inserted **postItem** template:

```
$('.more-less .more-block').css('height', 20).css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

**Template.postItem.rendered** affects all posts in page, but I need to affect only newly inserted post without affecting existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume new posts are added to the top of the list? if so...

```
<template name="postsList">
    <div class="posts-list">
    {{#each posts}}
        {{>postItem}}
    {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="postItem">
    <div class="more-less">
        <div class="more-block">
            <p>{{{text}}}</p>             
        </div>
        <p class="continued">…</p>
        <a href="#" class="show-more">[ + ]</a>
    </div>
</template>
```

You can simply achieve this with CSS:

```
.posts-list .more-less:first-child .more-block {
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

No need to use JavaScript and worry about reactivity and DOM mutation.

Comment: it does not solve my problem, because I need other operations on postItem except css